# There was an error starting the campaign target_time for running campaign should be at least 10 seconds in the future

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I'm encountering an issue while sending push notifications through Firebase. The problem arises when scheduling notifications, and a warning appears stating, "An error occurred starting the campaign: the target_time for running the campaign should be at least 10 seconds in the future[image]